# linalgerror: 2-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite and linalgerror(matrix is not positive definite)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, fluent-ffmpeg

I am making an animation based on data from a DataFrame, using graphics frames with seaborn, however the animation generally throws me the following error:

LinAlgError: 2-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite

Next I add python script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import seaborn as sns
import time

DF=pd.read_csv('Data.txt',header=None)
DF.columns=['Fecha','A','B','C']

DF['A']=DF['A'].astype(float)
DF['B']=DF['B'].astype(float)
DF['C']=DF['C'].astype(float)

DF.index=DF['Fecha']

Tasa.index=pd.to_datetime(Tasa.index)

aux=DF.loc['2013-01-01 00:00:00':'2013-01-01 23:59:00']

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax=fig.gca()

def create_frame(step,ax):
    ax.cla()
    sns.kdeplot(data=aux.iloc[:step], x='B',y='A', ax=ax,
                cmap='viridis',shade=True,shade_lowest=False)
    
    
    ax.set_ylabel('A',fontsize=20)
    ax.set_xlabel('B',fontsize=20)
    ax.set_ylim(4,10)
    ax.set_xlim(4,10)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x',labelsize=20)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y',labelsize=20)
    ax.grid(linewidth=2)
    ax.set_title(str(aux['Fecha'].iloc[:step] ))
    
anim=FuncAnimation(fig,create_frame,frames=1440,fargs=(ax,))

anim.save('animation.mp4',writer='ffmpeg',fps=60)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

I've tried some similar suggestions, but they don't solve the problem.
This error mainly affects the option to save in mp4 format.

Next I add a slice of the dataset I'm using.

```
Fecha,A,B,C
2013-01-01 00:00:00,6.14087783553993,6.487094209889805,-5.812500000000043
2013-01-01 00:01:00,6.142852535618053,6.451151448479498,-6.479166666666695
2013-01-01 00:02:00,6.135161728680298,6.434668659127371,-6.666666666666762
2013-01-01 00:03:00,6.188886372909593,6.409028544192662,-7.333333333333295
2013-01-01 00:04:00,6.151913845842533,6.44487051044415,-6.770833333333334
2013-01-01 00:05:00,6.264562948351688,6.454411146060466,-6.916666666666771
2013-01-01 00:06:00,6.242234273068323,6.445308053843112,-7.124999999999915
2013-01-01 00:07:00,6.174932891782772,6.441722354264567,-7.000000000000028
2013-01-01 00:08:00,6.232038731245972,6.449937844249292,-6.645833333333329
2013-01-01 00:09:00,6.165174653417497,6.467040915461258,-6.270833333333314
2013-01-01 00:10:00,6.3853883237758176,6.458878459987318,-7.083333333333286
2013-01-01 00:11:00,6.263194509011096,6.448655111416813,-7.312499999999981
2013-01-01 00:12:00,6.283530864000003,6.446058367626999,-7.4583333333333
2013-01-01 00:13:00,6.215382913023543,6.4055179472255785,-7.520833333333362
2013-01-01 00:14:00,6.1934735566462695,6.393851353700702,-7.458333333333418
2013-01-01 00:15:00,6.217458716653447,6.401671059300935,-7.145833333333348
2013-01-01 00:16:00,6.246137997753354,6.385379292241588,-7.395833333333357
2013-01-01 00:17:00,6.231281865441651,6.481968657909833,-6.375000000000004
2013-01-01 00:18:00,6.254048996078586,6.480787804043361,-6.541666666666639
2013-01-01 00:19:00,6.239227657414273,6.442150833993681,-6.270833333333314
2013-01-01 00:20:00,6.228536760812165,6.424125431870682,-6.270833333333314
2013-01-01 00:21:00,6.342729054767704,6.507853124943582,-5.916666666666734
2013-01-01 00:22:00,6.277015536846364,6.566158716794105,-5.7499999999999805
2013-01-01 00:23:00,6.568085114893764,6.519808967968322,-6.124999999999995
2013-01-01 00:24:00,6.498786250312206,6.519527637569746,-7.750000000000057
2013-01-01 00:25:00,6.416404536231541,6.601184637534719,-6.6041666666667
2013-01-01 00:26:00,6.35785606805381,6.747693362719629,-5.229166666666647
2013-01-01 00:27:00,6.495290996211007,6.713164189951006,-4.895833333333263
2013-01-01 00:28:00,6.294243543455379,6.572239151386452,-6.124999999999995
2013-01-01 00:29:00,6.398427884041256,6.557709169003854,-5.666666666666606
2013-01-01 00:30:00,6.878968144462191,6.631035770653698,-8.291666666666703
2013-01-01 00:31:00,6.8146252442834125,6.746498980678764,-8.437500000000023
2013-01-01 00:32:00,6.6844198909588,6.839763930725028,-7.91666666666669
2013-01-01 00:33:00,6.728784128217531,6.817158938901811,-7.333333333333295
2013-01-01 00:34:00,6.498238450745685,6.528099885819473,-8.000000000000066
2013-01-01 00:35:00,6.480660437855158,6.42654969045868,-8.52083333333328
2013-01-01 00:36:00,6.3860584491998,6.628162243121135,-7.4583333333333
2013-01-01 00:37:00,6.384143104338095,6.485055601614159,-6.895833333333338
2013-01-01 00:38:00,6.45619773851706,6.519968088488411,-6.937499999999967
2013-01-01 00:39:00,6.421997543203723,6.434096445944022,-6.70833333333339
2013-01-01 00:40:00,6.881147741740976,6.578590558037391,-7.541666666666677
2013-01-01 00:41:00,6.953754263971081,6.628791153680949,-9.958333333333396
2013-01-01 00:42:00,6.523773291513463,6.5788512074530665,-9.62500000000001
2013-01-01 00:43:00,6.444777581496862,6.576165879949302,-8.229166666666643
2013-01-01 00:44:00,6.574984483899018,6.594732317419947,-7.56249999999999
2013-01-01 00:45:00,6.574447377672005,6.614991689474629,-8.145833333333385
2013-01-01 00:46:00,6.288316930989483,6.594510925404618,-8.020833333333382
2013-01-01 00:47:00,6.188025686773623,6.579700619293616,-7.125000000000033
2013-01-01 00:48:00,6.365197487415873,6.538544964933211,-6.979166666666595
2013-01-01 00:49:00,6.515438957534605,6.570519350260649,-8.187500000000014
2013-01-01 00:50:00,6.380516809904227,6.799245312056565,-6.270833333333314
2013-01-01 00:51:00,6.386125396297558,7.042725808100298,-3.6666666666667664
2013-01-01 00:52:00,6.354051236532193,6.858146201951583,-4.58333333333331
2013-01-01 00:53:00,6.212102833544907,6.903736224451984,-3.8749999999999103
2013-01-01 00:54:00,6.15850848072259,6.610161808661356,-4.499999999999933
2013-01-01 00:55:00,6.171615592855998,6.761485582969952,-3.937499999999972
2013-01-01 00:56:00,6.170714336159644,6.722566953339712,-3.5208333333334467
2013-01-01 00:57:00,6.188783235230519,6.633411053647084,-3.791666666666652
2013-01-01 00:58:00,6.214425142758532,6.706620958764833,-4.062499999999977
2013-01-01 00:59:00,6.204858772635459,6.695525774296802,-4.499999999999933
```

Comment: Please provide sample dataset on which the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Responding to your comment, add a dataset that I'm using. I would appreciate any suggestions.